# ¿Cómo obtener los campos de un Pointer?

Tags: javascript, parse.com

Estoy tratando de obtener los campos de un `Pointer` de la forma sugerida en este [post](https://www.parse.com/questions/javascript-pointers-how-to-retrieve-fields-using-pointers-and-include-in-query) pero siempre me retorna `undefined`.

Tabla `Publication`:

- `userId` -> `User`
- `subCategoryId` -> `Subcategory`
- `title`
- `description`
- `budget`

Tabla `SubCategory`:

- `categoryId` -> `Category`
- `name`
- `isActive`

Y este el código que estoy intentando (solo tengo un registro en la tabla):

```
var user = Parse.User.current();
var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(User);
userQuery.equalTo("objectId", user.id);

var Publication = Parse.Object.extend("Publication");
var publicationQuery = new Parse.Query(Publication);
publicationQuery.include("subCategoryId");
publicationQuery.matchesQuery("userId", userQuery);        
publicationQuery.find({
    success: function(publications) {
        console.log(publications[0].get("title"));
        // Me retorna undefined
        console.log(publications[0].get("subCategoryId"));
    }
});
```

Lo que necesito hacer es:

```
publications[0].get("subCategoryId").get("name");
```

Pero lo anterior obviamente me retorna:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
```

---

[Cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734070/retrieving-information-from-pointer-field) en Stack Overflow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si usted tiene punteros en su base de datos de análisis como la siguiente, no hay necesidad de trabajar con los ObjectID.

[image]

Los datos que usted debe tener es algo como esto:

Publication:

- user (`Pointer <_User>`)
- subCategory (`Pointer <SubCategory>`)
- title (`String`)
- description (`String`)

SubCategory:

- category (`Pointer <Category>`)
- name (`String`)
- isActive (`boolean`)

Así que si usted está guardando los datos como se espera lo siguiente debe funcionar:

```
var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
var Publication = Parse.Object.extend("Publication");
var publicationQuery = new Parse.Query(Publication);
publicationQuery.equalTo("user", currentUser); 
publicationQuery.include("subCategory");       
publicationQuery.find({
    success: function(publications) {
        console.log(publications[0].get("title"));
        // This one returns undefined
        console.log(publications[0].get("subCategory").get("name");
    }
});
```

*Respuesta original [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734070/retrieving-information-from-pointer-field/34734320#34734320](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734070/retrieving-information-from-pointer-field/34734320#34734320_)*

Comment: Gracias, el problema era que la tabla estuvo mal definida, el Pointer "apuntaba" a la tabla equivocada, todo un dolor de cabeza